# How to fill available space with WebView inside

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to solve this problem. Basically I'm creating a function in which I will put a webview.

Both above this function and below this function there will be other UI components.

when I scroll up the part of the UI above the webview shrinks to half of its height.
What I do is to record the page scroll events to make this animation.

Unfortunately, however, it happens that the webview does not ONLY occupy the space available on the screen but in height it is as high as all the contents of the WebView. Below you can see what I would like to achieve in the first image:

[image]

And here instead what I actually get:

[image]

This is a problem because when a page asks to accept cookies and the relevant popup appears, being the page so high I get an overlay that looks like an error but is simply given by the popup that asks you to accept cookies and which however is below, and on some devices it is not even visible

What I am trying to achieve, unsuccessfully, would be the XML equivalent of `0dp`, in height.

To do this I thought I could use `ConstraintLayouts` for compose (`implementation ("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0")`) but they are not working. In fact, the result I get is as if I had "wrap content" and not `0dp` and in fact a small page shrinks the box, a large page expands beyond the size of the screen.

Below is the code I am using. I started with the new compose feature whose example is well explained in [**this link**](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/ui/samples/NestedScrollInteropSamples.kt;l=40?q=NestedScrollInteropSample)

```
private val ToolbarHeight = 300.dp

@Composable
fun CollapsingToolbarComposeViewComposeNestedScrollInteropSample(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val toolbarHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { ToolbarHeight.roundToPx().toFloat() }
    val toolbarOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value + delta
                toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value = newOffset.coerceIn(-toolbarHeightPx, 0f)
                logger.debug("Offset.Zero : ${Offset.Zero} .... $newOffset, $delta")

                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }

    // Compose Scrollable
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ) {

        // Android View
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context -> AndroidViewWithCompose(context, content) },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )

        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(ToolbarHeight)
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(
                        x = 0,
                        y = toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value
                            .coerceAtLeast(-200f)
                            .coerceAtMost(0f)
                            .roundToInt()
                    )
                },
            title = { Text("toolbar offset is ${toolbarOffsetHeightPx.value}") }
        )
    }
}

private fun AndroidViewWithCompose(context: Context, content: @Composable () -> Unit): View {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.three_fold_nested_scroll_interop, null).apply {
            with(findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view)) {
                // Compose
                setContent { LazyColumnWithNestedScrollInteropEnabled(content) }
            }
        }.also {
            ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(it, true)
        }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
private fun LazyColumnWithNestedScrollInteropEnabled(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    ConstraintLayout() {
        val (wv) = createRefs()
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(wv) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.top)
                }
                .nestedScroll(
                    rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()
                ),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = ToolbarHeight)
        ) {
            item {
                Text("This is a Lazy Column")
            }
            items(1) { _ ->
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `content()` is just my webView:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()

            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72259954/edit")
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Most of time you don't need `ConstraintLayout` in Compose, I don't know what's 0dp in XML world, probably not `Modifier.height(0.dp)`, please describe more clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @PylypDukhov What do you think? I have added as many details as possible

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but the sample you're trying to use here has quite different: it allows you to track `LazyColumn` scrolling from a nested `AndroidView`, you need to track web view scrolling.